# Why are temporally long SELECTs in SQLite blocking updates in other processes?

Tags: sqlite

I'm on a Mac, running 10.15.7. My SQLite version is 3.32.3.

I have a large SQLite database (16GB) against which the query behavior is kind of mystifying. I have a SELECT query which takes a very long time (between 20 and 30 seconds). If I start this query in one SQLite shell, and attempt to do an UPDATE in another SQLite shell, I can get a write lock, but the commit yields "database is locked" (which I'm pretty sure corresponds to SQLITE_BUSY):

```
sqlite> begin immediate transaction;
sqlite> update edges set suppressed = 1 where id = 1;
sqlite> end transaction;
Error: database is locked
```

As I understand SQLite, it supports parallel reads but exclusive writes, and I'm only doing a write in the shell shown here; the other one is just running an expensive SELECT. The documentation does say this:

> An attempt to execute COMMIT might also result in an SQLITE_BUSY return code if an another thread or process has an open read connection. When COMMIT fails in this way, the transaction remains active and the COMMIT can be retried later after the reader has had a chance to clear.

But I don't understand **why**, or under what circumstances this COMMIT behavior arises; it says "might", but it doesn't elaborate. Nor do I understand how this statement is consistent with the idea that SQLite is exclusive only with respect to writes.

Thanks to all in advance for an explanation.

Comment: In most journal modes, any active read locks will block a write lock from being acquired. You might look into WAL mode.

Comment: Thank you for the tip! Is this in the SQLite documentation anywhere? I couldn't really deduce this from reading the transaction or file-locking pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commenter Shawn is correct; the answer is that the default SQLite journal mode blocks a write lock if either a write or a read is underway. This is made clear [here](https://charlesleifer.com/blog/going-fast-with-sqlite-and-python/), although I couldn't find that mentioned in the core SQLite documentation.